# What's wrong with using a labelled statement in global code?

Tags: javascript, jslint, labeled-statements

I was just browsing the [source of JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) and noticed this piece of code:

```
// Is this a labeled statement?
//...
if (next_token.labeled !== true || funct === global_funct) {
    stop('unexpected_label_a', label);
} //...
```

The interesting part is the `funct === global_funct` comparison. Running the following snippet through JSLint throws an "Unexpected label" error, since the labelled statement is in the global execution context (I know, it's a stupid example. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/PnMsf/).):

```
loop:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 5) {
        break loop;
    }
}
```

If you place that same snippet in a function, JSLint is perfectly happy with it and doesn't throw an error when it encounters the label. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/PnMsf/2/) with code that will pass JSLint. The code can be pasted into the [online version of JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) if you want to try it.

So my question: is there anything wrong with using a labelled statement in global code or is it just another personal choice by Crockford?

Comment: It looks suspiciously like a variation on "Goto considered harmful."

Comment: I really hope this is not supported in modern javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It does indeed, but why behave differently in global code?

Comment: In a function, at least the damage is confined to inside the function. :)

Comment: @jbabey - I agree, there is very limited use for labelled statements, but the question remains... is there a difference when they are present in global code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think you're probably right. Pretty sure there's no actual difference according to the spec. Thanks :)

Comment: Would you use a library that employed a global label?  How about two libraries?  What if they used the same label?  What if you upgraded a library and it now employed a label that you were using in your own code?  It's pretty scary stuff!

Comment: There are uses for them, even in well-written code, IMHO.  But if you put them in the global scope, you run too many risks of collisions.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - I would be unlikely to use a library that didn't wrap itself in a function. Most do for precisely that reason - to avoid clashes with your own code. But that is another good point and quite possibly a major part of the decision in JSLint.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - often, though, libraries are built out of smaller files that don't themselves contain that wrapper.  JSLint running against those smaller files might only see the label as a global.  I'm not necessarily defending JSLint on this, but I'm guessing that's one of the reasons.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Yeah, it makes sense. I should have figured that out really with a bit of common sense. Too focused on the actual behaviour of the code to think about silly things like increased possibility of identifier conflicts :)

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Duplicate label identifiers should actually not cause any problems. They won't look good, and the code may not be as easy to understand, but it shouldn't cause any problems. See my answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Following a bit of investigation, I don't think there can be any damage, so I don't think there's any need to attempt to limit it! Would be interested if anyone can see a way labels in global scope can interfere with other code in global scope though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following some investigation into the behaviour of labelled statements, I think this is actually just a choice by Crockford with no real basis in fact. As far as I can tell, there is no situation that could cause a naming conflict with labels in the global scope (and that seemed to be the main reason people could think of for why JSLint disallows it - see comments on the question).

The ES5 spec states the following in the [section on labelled statements](http://es5.github.com/#x12.12):

> The production *Identifier : Statement* is evaluated by adding
>   *Identifier* to the label set of *Statement* and then evaluating *Statement*.
>
> ...
>
> Prior to the evaluation of a *LabelledStatement*, the contained *Statement* is regarded as possessing an empty label set, unless it is an *IterationStatement* or a *SwitchStatement*, in which case it is regarded as possessing a label set consisting of the single element, `empty`.

I take this to mean that every statement has a label set.  Label identifiers are independant of variable and function identifiers, so it's syntactically acceptable to have a label with the same identifier as a variable in the same scope. In other words, this is valid:

```
var label = "My Label";
label:
for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
    break label;
}
```

Since each statement has its own label set, this is also valid:

```
label:
for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
    //Looks for 'label' in label set of `break` statement, then `for` statement
    break label;
}
label:
for (var y = 5; y < 15; y++) {
    //Same again. Will never look for label outside the enclosing `for` statement
    break label;
}
```

Since you can label any statement (it's pointless, but it's possible), you can label a labelled statement:

```
another:
label:
for (var y = 5; y < 15; y++) {
    break label;
}
```

When this is the case, the spec states the following:

> If the *LabelledStatement* itself has a non-empty label set, these labels are also added to the label set of Statement before
>   evaluating it.

In the above snippet, the label set of the `for` statement contains two labels (`another` and `label`). It is possible to break to *either* of those labels from within the `for` statement.

And finally, the spec also states (emphasis added):

> Labelled statements are only used in conjunction with labelled `break`
>   and `continue` statements. **ECMAScript has no `goto` statement**.

So based on all that, I cannot think of a possible way for any labels in global code to interfere with other global code. Of course, it's highly unlikely you would want a program that contains multiple labels with the same identifier, and JSLint already prevents that by throwing a "label is already defined" error. But I don't think there should be any difference with how it treats labelled statements in the global execution context.